# How to remove text that appear in pagination button when it move to right side of table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I put pagination button on centre of table, it is ok:
[image: normal situation]

But I want to put right side of table, it appear alphabet 'p' on this button:
[image: pagination moved to the right]

Here my code,
    .ui-paginator {
    text-align: right;
}

Comment: ok, thanks for your editing and sry for adding java tag.

Comment: you forgot to add how you move it to the right in the first place

Comment: I reverted you edit since the question became totally useless without the images. And please add to your question the info to that I requested in the previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found answer to solve this one.
I just add

```
.ui-icon-seek-first 
{
    text-align : left !important;
}
.ui-icon-seek-prev 
{
    text-align : left !important;
}
.ui-icon-seek-end 
{
    text-align : left !important;
}
```

I think it is not good way. but I use this code, this 'p' is disappear.

[An image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rJpn.png)

Comment: Why is it not a good way? Because of the `important!`? Then make your selectors more specific.

Comment: Not because of !important. For my question is I want to delete this character 'p', according to my code, I just move this character 'p' to others place. Thats why i think not a good way. :)